# Ubuntu will NOT load, any method that I try

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I tried windows installer, did not work.

USB Drive, did not work.

LiveLinuxUSB, nothing.

CD-ROM, I got somewhere with this actually. By using the other three methods above, a colorful screen would appear. No, IT isn't the Ubuntu screen itself, It's green, blue, all sorts of colors. At first, I load it via CD, the Ubuntu screen does come up, it's purple colored with a few symbols at the bottom. The _ comes up as usual, then the colorful screen comes up, and then after that, It goes to saying VGA cable is not plugged in. I KNOW it's plugged in because I can see Windows 7 just perfectly.

Comment: First Check md5sum of downloaded iso of ubuntu that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

***Option 1***

Re-download the **.ISO** from Ubuntu download site, and burn a CD (under your Windows OS).  Make sure to verify the checksum, as @Ketan suggests, before burning.

Then proceed with install.

***Option 2***

Ask a friend.  Get them to create a USB install, from their existing **Ubuntu** machine.

***Both of these methods generally will work, even when nothing else will.  Good luck ..***

Answer (score 1):

It might be a graphics issue.  Try installing Ubuntu using the alternate CD.  The Alternate CD is text based installation, but the final outcome is the same as the live CD.  You can download the alternate CD [Here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)