# Unable to install ubuntu 12.04 on new motherboard

Tags: system-installation

Our PC configuration is as follows:
- ASUS Maximus V EXTREME LGA 1155 Intel Z77 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 Extended ATX Intel Motherboard 
- Intel Core i7-3770S Ivy Bridge 3.1GHz (3.9GHz Turbo) LGA 1155 65W Quad-Core Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 4000 BX80637I73770S

Windows 7 installation can proceed without any issues, but not Ubuntu. I tried 11.10 and 12.04 both 32bit and 64bit, same issue.

I have the BIOS settings to boot from CD drive. While booting, I get at the first screen with the little person and keyboard icons, then goes to Ubuntu splash screen and stays there forever. Only option is a hard reboot.

Can anyone share their experience with the motherboard I am using? Any suggestions for me to try?

Thanks.

Comment: Try pressing F6 when you see the man and keyboard, and then select nomodeset(Check it), press Escape and then select an option using the arrow keys.

Comment: See my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/174506/ubuntu-will-not-load-any-method-that-i-try/174686#174686), and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `nomodeset` to the boot options fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure also that you aren't trying to boot off of a drive that is plugged into the ASMedia eSATA ports.

This person reports that with the ASUS Maximus V Gene, which is like the little brother of the Extreme, they had a similar issue and [solved it by using the Intel eSATA ports](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1997046&page=2).

[ASUS has a footnote about those ASMedia ports](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/Maximus_V_Extreme/#specifications):

> These SATA ports are for data drives only.

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to boot with minimal/safe options. Then while installation is running (or after the installation), you can have live updates for new drivers related to your hardware. Please see this post https://askubuntu.com/a/102441/37991 for using safe options at boot time.

Comment: I tried the procedure mentioned in http://askubuntu.com/a/102441/37991, still didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this problem today. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in UEFI mode. I did the whole "custom BIOS partition with GParted + flags" thing. When it still wouldn't boot, I really scratched my head.

**Silly me.**

The solution is to update your BIOS firmware to the latest version. ASUS has offered quite a few updates for the Maximus V series motherboards.

### How to update Asus Maximus Series Motherboard BIOS

- Format a USB thumbdrive as FAT32 or MS-DOS
- Download the [latest BIOS firmware from Asus for Maximus Extreme](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/MAXIMUS_VI_EXTREME/HelpDesk_Download/)
- Extract the downloaded `.zip` and rename the file to `M5E.CAP`
- Copy `M5E.CAP` to the thumbdrive's root directory, then eject it
- Plug the USB thumbdrive into the designated BIOS update USB port (it should be outlined/called out on the rear motherboard port shield
- Reboot your machine and press F2/DEL to enter the BIOS, then use the easy updater tool to apply the `M5E.CAP` update
- Reboot and try your UEFI, non-windoze OS ;)